# Proving infinite conjunctions hold in almost all structures in a class

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I am trying to prove that almost all structures in a class satisfy a countably infinite conjunction of first-order sentences (in the sense that the limit of the proportion of structures that satisfy the conjunction tends to 1 as the size of the structures increases). I was wondering if there are any results that give sufficient conditions for this happening? For example, I know that each term in the conjunction almost always holds, and that there is a function f such that the limit of the number of n element structures satisfying the first f(n) terms of the conjunction tends to 1, so results based on conditions like this would be most useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is too broad. Certainly there can be no result with hypotheses as general as yours. For example, let $P_n$ be the property "there are at least $n$ elements". Then $\bigwedge_{i<n}P_n$ holds with probability $1$ on structures of size $\geq n$, but the infinite conjunction $\bigwedge_{i\in \omega} P_n$ does not hold of any finite structures.

Perhaps if you gave more information about the infinite conjunction you're interested in, I could say more.

Comment: Sure. I'm looking at the atom structures of finite integral relation algebras. The sentences are of the form $\forall x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_m\colon x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_m \neq e \to (\exists z\colon (z \neq e) \& C(x_1,y_1,z) \& \cdots \& C(x_m,y_m,z))$ for each $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$; they are from the article Finite Integral Relation Algebras by Roger Maddux, where these structures are defined. Almost all of these atom structures belong to a class that has a Fraïssé limit, so this class has the hereditary property and the amalgamation property. There is also a 0-1 law for this class.

Comment: @Tritone What is $C$?

Comment: It's a ternary relation symbol in that signature

Comment: Write $\varphi_m$ for the sentence your wrote in your first comment. Then a finite structure satisfies $\bigwedge_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^+} \varphi_m$ if and only if it satisfies the following sentence $\psi$: $\exists z\, ((z\neq e\land \forall x\forall y\, (x\neq e\land y\neq e)\rightarrow C(x,y,z)))$.

Comment: Why? In one direction, $\psi$ implies $\bigwedge_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^+} \varphi_n$ in every structure. In the other direction, if $M$ is a finite structure, we can enumerate the pairs $(a,b)\in M^2$ with $a\neq e$ and $b\neq e$ as $(a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_m,b_m)$. Then if $M\models \varphi_m$, it satisfies $\psi$. So we've returned the problem to understanding which first-order sentences are true almost surely in  your class. Of course, this argument used the special form of $\varphi_m$, but a similar argument will apply for the $\forall \exists$ extension axioms that axiomatize Fraïssé limits.

Comment: Unfortunately that sentence almost never holds. I'll have to think of some weaker sentences that still imply what I want. Thank you so much for your help!